# Is there a function that will list packages required for knitting an Rmd or Rnw file?

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, knitr, sweave

RStudio detects if package(s) required for knitting an Rnw or Rmd file are not installed.  It therefore has a mechanism that it can use to check what packages are required.  Is there a function, available to RStudio or R users more generally, that will list the package names?

Comment: Konrad Rudolph's answer in the dup looks very relevant.